# algorithm2e caption above code with conference style files

Tags: algorithm2e

I am trying to put the caption above the code using [COLT'17 conference latex styles](http://www.learningtheory.org/colt2017/for-authors-2/submission-instructions/). There is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147747/algorithm2e-caption-above-code), but their solution doesn't seem to work when combined with the COLT latex style:

```
\documentclass[anon,12pt]{colt2017} % includes algorithm2e, I believe in jmlr.cls

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@algocf@capt@plain}{above}% formerly {bottom}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Also, I would like to add horizontal lines as separators (which are usually enabled by \usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Small warning: conferences aim for uniformity in presentation, and therefore they may not like it when you change the behavior of their classes.

Comment: Though I agree with Marijn that conferences provide their classes to conserve uniformity between articles, is this question still open ?