# Wrong anchor of algorithm2e with caption on top

Tags: hyperref, captions, algorithm2e, anchor, hypertarget

I have the following MWE, where I use the package `algorithm2e` to print algorithms. However, I like the captions of the algorithms to be placed on the top (how to do this was already answered in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147747/algorithm2e-caption-above-code)). The placement of the caption works fine.

Unfortunately, the `hyperref` anchor is placed in the wrong place. When I click the link, the page jumps to the bottom line "Return" of the algorithm. How can I make it jump such that the caption is the first line on the display?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147747/algorithm2e-caption-above-code
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@algocf@capt@boxed}{above} % formerly {bottom}
\makeatother

\usepackage[linkcolor=red]{hyperref}    

\begin{document}

Algorithm~\ref{algo:myalgo}.

\begin{algorithm}
    Do something.\\
    Calculate something.\\
    Erase something.\\
    Return.
    \caption{The caption}
    \label{algo:myalgo}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147747/algorithm2e-caption-above-code
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@algocf@capt@boxed}{above} % formerly {bottom}
\renewcommand{\algocf@caption@boxed}{\vskip\AlCapSkip\MakeLinkTarget[topalgocf]{algocf}\box\algocf@capbox}%
\patchcmd\algocf@caption@algo
    {\hyper@refstepcounter{algocf}}
    {\hyper@refstepcounter{algocf}\xdef\@currentHref{top\@currentHref}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage[linkcolor=red]{hyperref}    

\begin{document}

Algorithm~\ref{algo:myalgo}.


\begin{algorithm}
    Do something.\\
    Calculate something.\\
    Erase something.\\
    Return.
    \caption{The caption}\label{algo:myalgo}    
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get the error "Undefined control sequence. \end{algorithm}"

Comment: you should look into the log-file to get the real error, don't rely on the summary of your editor. But if I should guess I would say your texsystem is not up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that solved the issue.